# How can I use Url.Content() in MVC4 with parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, caching, cache-manifest

Here is my code:

```
@Url.Content("~/AspNetWebForms/ViewPDF.aspx?id=" + docID.ToString() + "&small=True")
```

I am dynamically building my Manifest file for Application Caching in MVC4. I know it's on the way out (or appears to be) but I do still need to support older browsers.

The site is in MVC, but we do have a couple ASPX pages because we need to use some legacy controls. So in my manifest file I am trying to create a relative path to the ASPX pages using Url.Content(), which seems to work until I need to add a couple parameters and the "&" is encoded. Without the "&" it seems to work (except that it loads/caches the wrong thing).

And since it's a manifest file, I cannot do a redirect, as any redirect causes the application cache to fail.

Even though it's MVC4, I cannot just start with the "~" because it doesn't get parsed as it would in an image or anchor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first I thought it was the Url.Content that was encoding the value, but it's actually the Razor engine doing it. Html.Raw corrected it, though I did have to add an empty line afterwards as the line break was lost, too.

```
@Html.Raw(Url.Content("~/AspNetWebForms/ViewPDF.aspx?id=" + docID.ToString() + "&small=True"))
```

Paul Abbott's answer lead me to this conclusion so all thanks to him.

Comment: There has to be a better way to do this... Something similar to Url.Action but without having to use a Controller? Any thoughts?

Comment: @pjdupreez This doesn't use a controller. Just the Razor view.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but it does not allow you to pass parameters, similar to Url.Action (which does need a controller) so you have to build your query string by hand.

Answer (score 4):

Just append the query string to the output of `Url.Content` instead.

```
@(Url.Content("~/AspNetWebForms/ViewPDF.aspx) + "?id=" + docID.ToString() + "&small=True")
```

or

```
@string.Format("{0}?id={1}&small=true", 
    Url.Content("~/AspNetWebForms/ViewPDF.aspx"), docID.ToString())
```

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of these works. They both result in an encoded ampersand.